# Rails update model from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

So I have this 2 models, Folder and Event. Folder have_one Event and Event belongs to Folder.

I want to be able to update a folder's event with new attributes at the same time as the folder. Something like this.

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.update(folder_params)
        @folder.event.update_attributes(status: @folder.status)
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @folder }
      else
        format.html { :edit }
        format.json { render json: @folder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

But I understand this is not very MVC compliant and also does not work. So any idea on how I can make this work ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just updating the status or are there actually more than just this one attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_save :update_event_status, on: update  #Or after_update :update_event_status

    def update_event_status
        event.update_attributes(status: status)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

write method in Model and call it in controller method. like below code.

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base

    def update_event_status(event,status)
        event.update_attributes(status: status)
    end

end


def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.update(folder_params)
        update_event_status(@folder.event,@folder.status) #call methode here
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @folder }
      else
        format.html { :edit }
        format.json { render json: @folder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Try this.

Comment: Works well thanks. @nmeylan method is cleaner though